# Are there any specific supernatural/scientific creatures which might fuse and grant abilities to a person?

Tags: creature-design, science-fiction, super-powers, mythical-creatures, supernatural

A character of mine gains certain abilities after a creature fuses with em as he dies. However, I don’t know of any supernatural creature that would do this or something similar which might explain the phenomenon in the story. I could make one up, but having it based on something would help me make decisions about the world around it and keep things related.

The story itself centers around disillusionment, and the abilities the character obtains is supposed to reflect a drastic psychological shift in the character.

Any creature or being that might bind to a person, react to/be affected by their psyche, and give them supernatural abilities is what I’m looking for.

For more context:
The story itself explores disillusionment.
The character is outcasted royalty (survived an insurrection against the royal family) whom is betrayed by es would-be lover and left to die in a mysterious wood.

This event, compounding on past events over the character’s lifetime, inspires a passion for vengeance in the character and a drastic psychological shift.

This shift results in the character’s yang and yin traits inverting, (essentially replacing each-other), reflected in how the supernatural abilities gained are based in fire, light, and rigid kinetic energy.

Additionally, the character’s body is warped somewhat thematically, as es hands— which used to tend gardens and write— rot away, and the only way for the character to sustain itself is through extracellular digestion (like fungi); e’s weakened substantially by darkness, cold and water (unless it's boiling hot); and es eyes glow among other aesthetic changes (sharp teeth, floaty hair, constant buzzing noise)

Comment: I think you might revise your question, as the question seems to be mostly focused on asking about fantasy elements, specifically in a way that makes it difficult to answer.

Comment: Welcome Brown, please take our [tour] and refer to our [help] for guidance as to our ways. I must say, your use of e and em is my favourite genderless pronoun use so far, it's much less jarring to the eye than many alternatives I've seen. Anyhow, enjoy the site.

Comment: @A Rogue Ant.  Thank you, it’s a relief to hear that it does what I want it to do. I appreciate the welcome too ✨

Comment: Brown why did you edit all that good stuff out?  That was the stuff that gave a clue what sort of thing you are looking for.

Comment: Wilk I think I just didn’t organize it well; I do have a habit of over explaining things to the point of tangents which does tend to make my initial focus hard to understand. I’ll add in the extra stuff  back in but this time in its own section for context. Thanks for pointing that out :,0

Comment: Are you asking for examples from human mythology, in which case the two existing answers are on-topic? Or are you asking for *existing insects or animals* that could mimic the behaviors you're asking about, in which case ***both*** answers are off-topic? Frankly, the way your Q currently reads, it appears you want the latter, not the former.

Comment: Join JBH, Either is very useful, this creature could be based on myth or animals. I’ll end up tweaking it either way to fit the story (Similar to how the Panda was depicted as a guardian spirit in Avatar: The last airbender). While I think a supernatural creature would fit better (or just be easier to find), I’d be just as grateful if someone suggested an animal with similar behavior. I could even combine them to reinforce the nature of the creature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Possessed by devils**

[Book of Mark, 5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%205%3A1-20&version=KJV)

> 5 And they came over unto the other side of the sea, into the country
> of the Gadarenes.
>
> 2 And when he was come out of the ship, immediately there met him out
> of the tombs a man with an unclean spirit,
>
> 3 Who had his dwelling among the tombs; and no man could bind him, no,
> not with chains:
>
> 4 Because that he had been often bound with fetters and chains, and
> the chains had been plucked asunder by him, and the fetters broken in
> pieces: neither could any man tame him.
>
> 5 And always, night and day, he was in the mountains, and in the
> tombs, crying, and cutting himself with stones.
>
> 6 But when he saw Jesus afar off, he ran and worshipped him,
>
> 7 And cried with a loud voice, and said, What have I to do with thee,
> Jesus, thou Son of the most high God? I adjure thee by God, that thou
> torment me not.
>
> 8 For he said unto him, Come out of the man, thou unclean spirit.
>
> 9 And he asked him, What is thy name? And he answered, saying, **My name
> is Legion: for we are many**.
>
> 10 And he besought him much that he would not send them away out of
> the country.
>
> 11 Now there was there nigh unto the mountains a great herd of swine
> feeding.
>
> 12 And all the devils besought him, saying, Send us into the swine,
> that we may enter into them.
>
> 13 And forthwith Jesus gave them leave. And the unclean spirits went
> out, and entered into the swine: and the herd ran violently down a
> steep place into the sea, (they were about two thousand;) and were
> choked in the sea.

All that you are looking for.  Unclean spirits get in this guy.  He has super powers, and cannot be bound.  He is tortured by the devils in him, crying and cutting himself.  And when Jesus shows up, it is the devils that recognize and address Jesus, and plead with him.

It is what you describe: demonic possession.  This is a compellingly weird passage and I think it lurks in the backs of the minds of anyone raised in the Christian tradition.  The fact that the supernatural powers have a voice and worship Jesus and plead their case makes it extra creepy.  They are
malign supernatural powers but they did not hate Jesus as we are accustomed to think such things must.  And also creepy that Jesus actually respected their request - he did not send them out of the country but just out of the man.

If you are writing a story, opening with a biblical verse is a fine way to start.  And "My name is Legion" is one of the most chilling verses there is.

Comment: Thank you Willk! This is a very interesting idea, I really like the greyness of it and its relation to what could be considered a symbol of good.

Comment: I’ll see if I can’t find more on the Legion

Comment: @Brown - it really makes me think.  What were those things?  Were they also trapped?  The pigs were their idea, and then they killed the pigs.  Is that what they needed?  It is such a trip when the Bible mentions powers outside of human and divine, good and evil.   Something like that is what was in the forest in your story.  It did not want to be joined with your character.  It too is trapped.

Comment: Yes, in a way. The binding is not the creature’s intention. And I’m not sure that there *is* any specification on what the Legion was, while I see some allusionary uses that make it seem intimidating, I have a feeling it’s was more of a residual being with no real malicious intent but was nonetheless destructive.

Answer (score 2):

**[The Alkonost](https://www.topinspired.com/mythical-birds/)**

This creature of Russian legend is said to be able to sooth all worries and remove all longing by its song:

> The Alkonost is a mythical creature with the head of a woman and the
> body of a bird. What makes it unique? The Alkonost sings the most
> enchanting melodies. Those who heard its song let go of everything
> they had ever known. They desire nothing more[...].
>
> Before Christian influence, many considered the Alkonost a wind
> spirit, able to summon up storms. This bird lays its eggs on the
> gently sloping seashore and moves them into the sea to hatch.

However, seeing as this just applies a psychic soothing balm, as soon as your character stops singing, their problems and troubles are still very much there.

Comment: I do remember seeing something about the Alkonost, but I never knew it sang or could effect people. While I don’t think it would fit as the thing that fuses *with* the character, it would fit into a certain event that happens *to* the character.

Answer (score 2):

> Additionally, the character’s body is warped somewhat thematically, as es hands— which used to tend gardens and write— rot away, and the only way for the character to sustain eself is through extracellular digestion (like fungi); e’s weakened substantially by darkness, cold and water (unless its boiling hot); and es eyes glow among other aesthetic changes (sharp teeth, floaty hair, constant buzzing noise)

This could be one of a number of parasites. There are a lot of [behaviour-altering parasites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-altering_parasite). [Ophiocordyceps unilateralis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophiocordyceps_unilateralis) is a fungus that alters the behaviour of ants, making them move to locations with specific temperature and humidity (though the fungus likes high humidity).

You could even use a [hyperparasite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparasite), where a fungus infects insects, and those insects infect the character. Some of the changes you want can be due to the fungus, and some to the insects. Maybe the insects are drawn out of the body by water, but the fungus wants to stay in the body, so it makes the person avoid water. The fungus could [glow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bioluminescent_fungus_species), and the backlight in the eyes makes the person's vision weaker, so e avoids the dark. The insects make the buzzing sound. The fungus does the extracellular digestion and rots the hands. The whole systems messes up the person's body, so their gums recede and teeth get brittle and chip sharp, and their hair gets thin so it stands up more easily - e gets a lot of static since e stays in hot dry areas.

Since the story is about disillusionment, the character might have to agree to let the fungus take over to prevent the insects from just eating em.